# How to ignore the line breaks in BeautifulSoup parser in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Ok, here I go with my first question. 
I am trying to parse some content from a website with BeautifulSoup. The content I want to grab is in a td tag; but sometimes comes as two lines and other times not (includes a line break in the code)

Example for a bulldog:

sometimes `<td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog</td>`
other times `<td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog<br/>French</td>`"

When I use the following to make a list of the dog breeds:

```
for db in soup.body.find_all('td', class_="searchResultsDogBreed"):
         list_dogbreed.append(db.text.strip())
```

it brings the some results as **BulldogFrench** as expected since it strips all spaces. I want to either ignore the French and have only **Bulldog** since I only care if it is a bulldog or not, or at least list it so that the output is "Bulldog French" so that I can separate the two words.

I have to strip spaces somehow because the actual output without strip() is something like

```
"                               BulldogFrench      "
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: first `split()` and get first element, and later `strip()` it.

Answer (score 1):

`BeautifulSoup` has special function `get_text()` which has option `separator` to separate text from different children. As default it uses empty string as separtor so you get `BulldogFrench` but you can use space as separtor. If you have strings with spaces which you want to keep then you can use some unique char like `|` to use later `split("|")`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''
<td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog1</td>
<td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog2<br/>French</td>
'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_items = soup.find_all('td')
for item in all_items:
    text = item.get_text(separator='|')
    print('before:', text)
    text = text.split('|')[0]
    print('after:', text)
```

Result:

```
before: Bulldog1
 after: Bulldog1
---
before: Bulldog2|French
 after: Bulldog2
---
```

**BTW:** `get_text()` has also option `strip=True` to remove spaces before joining elements to one string - it can be useful when you have many spaces between elements.

---

You can also use `.children` to create list with all subelements and get only first element

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''
<td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog1</td>
<td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog2<br/>French</td>
'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_items = soup.find_all('td')
for item in all_items:
    elements = list(item.children)
    print('  All:', elements)
    print('First:', elements[0])
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
  All: ['Bulldog1']
First: Bulldog1
---
  All: ['Bulldog2', <br/>, 'French']
First: Bulldog2
```

**BTW:** to get only text elements

```
elements = [x for x in item.children if isinstance(x, str)]
```

Result:

```
All: ['Bulldog1']
All: ['Bulldog2', 'French']
```

---

**EDIT:** Instead of `list(item.children)` you can try

```
elements = item.contents
```

You can also try `item.next` but it may get next `td` (or `\n`) if current `td` is empty.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''
<td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog1</td>
<td class="searchResultsDogBreed"></td>
<td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog2<br/>French</td>
'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')
all_items = soup.find_all('td')

for item in all_items:
    print('    item:', item)
    print('children:', list(item.children))
    print('contents:', item.contents)
    print('    next:', item.next)
    print(' 2x next:', item.next.next)
    print(' 3x next:', item.next.next.next)
    #elements = list(item.children)
    elements = item.contents
    #elements = [x for x in item.children if isinstance(x, str)]
    print('     All:', elements)
    if elements:
        print('   First:', elements[0])
    else:
        print('   First:')
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
   item: <td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog1</td>
children: ['Bulldog1']
contents: ['Bulldog1']
    next: Bulldog1
 2x next: 

 3x next: <td class="searchResultsDogBreed"></td>
     All: ['Bulldog1']
   First: Bulldog1
---
    item: <td class="searchResultsDogBreed"></td>
children: []
contents: []
    next: 

 2x next: <td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog2<br/>French</td>
 3x next: Bulldog2
     All: []
   First:
---
    item: <td class="searchResultsDogBreed">Bulldog2<br/>French</td>
children: ['Bulldog2', <br/>, 'French']
contents: ['Bulldog2', <br/>, 'French']
    next: Bulldog2
 2x next: <br/>
 3x next: French
     All: ['Bulldog2', <br/>, 'French']
   First: Bulldog2
---
```